# How to center a NSTextField in a view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

i've a NSTextField (label) centered with IB in a view with the text "__DRAG_AND_DROP_YOUR_MEDIA_HERE". In my controller a use NSLocalizedString to translate the text :

English.lproj/Localizable.strings :

```
"__DRAG_AND_DROP_YOUR_MEDIA_HERE" = "Drag & Drop your media here"
```

French.lproj/Localizable.strings :

```
"__DRAG_AND_DROP_YOUR_MEDIA_HERE" = "Déposer vos média ici"
```

Only the initial text "__DRAG_AND_DROP_YOUR_MEDIA_HERE" is centerred in the view. The translated text is not centerrd (depending on is lenght). All the translated text start at the same absciss x than the orignal text. How can i fix this issue ?

PS: I don't want to play with setFrame, height, width just for a simple point like this. I guess there's another method to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you center justify the text in your NSTextField?  Perhaps one just appears centered because the english version is longer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the text field's alignment to `NSCenterTextAlignment`. You can do this from IB or programmatically using `-setAlignment:`.

Comment: Text was already centered. I use the IB option : Fill container horizontally and it works !

Comment: Is anyone else having issues doing this programmatically?